# How to install doxygen with Eclipse

Tags: php, eclipse, documentation, doxygen

I have never used any documentation software. Now I need to use doxygen for JavaScript files.

I am using Eclipse as code editor but don't know how to use doxygen with classic Eclipse for JavaScript files.

I have installed this

http://www.mantidproject.org/Eclipse_Doxygen_Setup

Then I can see doxygen tab in preferences but it says "add Doxygen version", which I don't know how to add.

What do I do now?

Answer (score 0):

Go to preferences -> Doxygen click at the "Add..." button and browse to the bin folder of doxygen (should be "C:\Program Files\doxygen\bin" if you didn't change the installation destination of doxygen).